# JS to redirect to a splash page on first visit?

Tags: javascript, redirect, cookies

I'm trying to modify some code to direct users to a "create an account" squeeze page on their first visit. I think I'm close, but I need a little help. Any advise on where I went wrong?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    // check cookie
    var visited = $.cookie("visited")

    if (visited == null) {
        window.location = "content/content-article.asp?ArticleID=4998"
        $.cookie('visited', 'yes'); 
        alert($.cookie("visited"));         
    }

    // set cookie
    $.cookie('visited', 'yes', { expires: 10,000, path: '/' });
});
```

Comment: You have to tell us what went wrong

Comment: what is the error u r getting?

Comment: Could it be that `10,000` that should actually be `10000` or `1e4`?

Comment: I'm not getting an error, it's just not redirecting. Here is the test page: http://www.pitchrate.com/content/content-article.asp?ArticleID=4999

Comment: and the updated code:
    <script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function() {
    // check cookie
    var visited = $.cookie("visited")

    // set cookie
    $.cookie('visited', 'yes', { expires: 1e4, path: '/' });

    if (visited == null) {
        $.cookie('visited', 'yes'); 
        alert($.cookie("visited"));         
        window.location = "http://www.pitchrate.com/content/content-article.asp?ArticleID=4998"
    }
});

</script>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK - I kept digging and found a different script that worked. Here it is in case someone else is trying to do the same thing:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function redirect(){
var thecookie = readCookie('doRedirect');
if(!thecookie){window.location = 'http://yournetwork.com/splash';
}}function createCookie(name,value,days){if (days){var date = new Date();date.setTime(date.getTime()+(days*24*60*60*1000));var expires = "; expires="+date.toGMTString();}else var expires = "";document.cookie = name+"="+value+expires+"; path=/";}function readCookie(name){var nameEQ = name + "=";var ca = document.cookie.split(';');for(var i=0;i < ca.length;i++){var c = ca[i];while (c.charAt(0)==' ') c = c.substring(1,c.length);if (c.indexOf(nameEQ) == 0) return c.substring(nameEQ.length,c.length);}return null;}window.onload = function(){redirect();createCookie('doRedirect','true','999');}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // check cookie
    var visited = $.cookie("visited")

    // set cookie
    $.cookie('visited', 'yes', { expires: 10,000, path: '/' });

    if (visited == null) {
        $.cookie('visited', 'yes'); 
        alert($.cookie("visited"));         
        window.location = "content/content-article.asp?ArticleID=4998"
    }
});
```

Change the location to another site AFTER executing your code

Comment: I tried these changes as well as changing the 10,000 to 1e4 - still no joy.