# How to make JS page redirect trigger before page load

Tags: javascript, redirect, cookies, onload

I am using the following script to redirect visitors of a page to another page on first visit, however it loads the index.html page first, and then triggers the redirect. Can anyone point me in the direction of how I might trigger this script before the page loads?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function redirect(){
    var thecookie = readCookie('doRedirect');
    if(!thecookie){window.location = '/coming-soon.html';
    }}
    function createCookie(name,value,days){if (days){
    var date = new Date();date.setTime(date.getTime()+(days*24*60*60*1000));
    var expires = "; expires="+date.toGMTString();
    }
    else var expires = "";document.cookie = name+"="+value+expires+"; path=/";
    }
    function readCookie(name){
    var nameEQ = name + "=";var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
    for(var i=0;i < ca.length;i++){
    var c = ca[i];while (c.charAt(0)==' ') c = c.substring(1,c.length);
    if (c.indexOf(nameEQ) == 0) return c.substring(nameEQ.length,c.length);}
    return null;
    }
    window.onload = function(){redirect();createCookie('doRedirect','true','1');}
</script>
```

(the JS snippet used here was taken from [Stack Overflow: JS to redirect to a splash page on first visit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10853523/js-to-redirect-to-a-splash-page-on-first-visit))

Thanks.

Comment: don't do it in `window.onload` callback. Just put this code in head tag, then browser will run it as far as it parsed it. Also you'll better create cookie before redirect to ensure it executed.

Comment: To clarify, you mean change the last line to this? `function(){redirect();createCookie('doRedirect','true','1');}`

Comment: Sorry, don't get your last question. What is "this"?

Comment: Edited! Hit enter too soon.

Comment: I posted what I meant as answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to wait while window is loaded:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var thecookie = readCookie('doRedirect');
    if(!thecookie) {
       createCookie('doRedirect','true','1');
       window.location = '/coming-soon.html';
    };
    function createCookie(name,value,days){
      // do work
    }
    function readCookie(name){
      // do work
    }
</script>
```

Also Petr B. said right thing: server-side redirect is better in your case.

Comment: Thanks, this worked perfectly. As it's only a short-term solution I'll stick with this for now, as I'm not yet comfortable with server-side work, but will keep it in mind for future. Much appreciated.

Comment: This is the correct answer. However, to ensure the script is loaded before the body, add the script in `head`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this [How to Run a jQuery or JavaScript Before Page Start to Load](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3930199/how-to-run-a-jquery-or-javascript-before-page-start-to-load).

Btw. if you want redirect without displaying page you must use php with cookies check.