# check login and redirect before page load

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, cookies

Is it possible using javascript to stop a page from loading and redirect if a cookie is not set. lets say the page index.html requires you to be logged in, and the only way to log in is via a cookie given by the page login.html how can i stop index.html loading and then redirect the user to login.html.

Thanks in advance, i know how to do this in PHP but im having issues in javascript as it executes after the page loads and by then the user could just view-source:index.html to view the source code.

Comment: If it's JavaScript be wary that the user could always turn it off and view your page

Comment: hadn't thought of that thanks :P

Comment: is there any way of doing it with javascript then or would i have to use php?

Comment: In other words client-side authentication is almost always a big no

Comment: Does this work? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17420694/how-to-make-js-page-redirect-trigger-before-page-load. But PHP is much preferred.

Comment: il check, give me 5 mins :), I love PHP

Comment: Okay this works but the page displays, so i need to use server side. Back to PHP it is!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it is possible to load javascript before the page loads using the example below

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var thecookie = readCookie('doRedirect');
if(!thecookie) {
   createCookie('doRedirect','true','1');
   window.location = '/coming-soon.html';
};
function createCookie(name,value,days){
  // do work
}
function readCookie(name){
  // do work
}
</script>
```

But the page still displays, therefore the use of server side authentication is preferred using something like PHP.