# How to redirect an authenticated user (using JSON Web Token & local storage) from a landing page to the secure part of the site in one request?

Tags: local-storage, jwt

Currently implementing a JSON Web Token authentication system for user registration, login, etc. There are 2 parts to the site:

example.com/home - non-secure that anyone can access this

example.com/dashboard - secure, for authorised users only

When an authenticated user lands on example.com/home (insecure part) I'd like to automatically redirect them to the secure part (if authenticated of course.)

But it seems that the homepage would first have to load then Javascript would need to make an AJAX request to the server to authenticate any JWT passed by Javascript from LocalStorage.

Obviously, this seems like a wasteful extra step as cookies would be sent in the initial request but LocalStorage data would not. But I'd like to avoid cookies if possible.

Is there a workaround for this?

Comment: Why are you checking the local storage? You should check at the backend through the use of your session if the user is authenticated. A filter should handle that and redirect the user to the secure part.

Comment: @luke-bajada : I'm not using sessions at all as this is a purely token-based authentication system - JWT's are manually added to be sent with each request, and stored in the clients LocalStorage rather than being stored in cookies.

Comment: So I'm guessing you're using something similar to the OAuth 2.0 Implicit flow. In that case, I would advise to store the token as a cookie instead and read that cookie at the server side to provide redirection. There's no way to read LocalStorage from the server side. Also, be aware of the security implications of storing the cookie at the client side level.

Comment: @luke-bajada : ah, that's what I thought. I'm using LocalStorage and avoiding cookies to defend against certain attacks. So using LocalStorage there is no choice but to allow the first page to load, keep the screen blank, then redirect to the secure area if authorised to do so.

Comment: Something similar regarding functionality was already answered in [How to make JS page redirect trigger before page load](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17420694/how-to-make-js-page-redirect-trigger-before-page-load)

Answer (score 0):

After further research it would appear that there is no workaround for this. LocalStorage can only be read by Javascript rather than being automatically sent (like cookies can be) by the browser.

So the client would make a request, receive the request, either redirect to an authentication page (using JS to include any LocalStorage token) or make an AJAX request (using JS to include any LocalStorage token).

Also, using LocalStorage rather than cookies to store the token brings about other issues such as what happens when an authenticated user tries to open the same secure URL in another tab or window.

Such a time consuming subject full of varying opinions. I need a coffee...